# C# Bitmap image masking using unsafe code

Tags: c#, bitmap, unsafe

I'm using the following code to make image masks in C#:

```
for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.White);
    }
}

for(int x = left; x < width; x++)
{
    for(int y = top; y < height; y++)
    {
        bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.Transparent);
    }
}
```

But it's WAY too slow... What is the unsafe equivalent to this? Will it be allot faster?

In the end I do a bmp.Save() in PNG format.

**UPDATE:**

After reading through *[Link removed, dangerous site]* as suggested by MusiGenesis, I made it work using the following code (for anyone who needs it):

```
Bitmap     bmp = new Bitmap(1000,1000,PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
BitmapData bmd = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width,bmp.Height), 
                                  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, 
                                  bmp.PixelFormat);

int PixelSize=4;

unsafe 
{
    for(int y=0; y<bmd.Height; y++)
    {
        byte* row=(byte *)bmd.Scan0+(y*bmd.Stride);

        for(int x=0; x<bmd.Width; x++)
        {
            row[x*PixelSize]     = 0;   //Blue  0-255
            row[x*PixelSize + 1] = 255; //Green 0-255
            row[x*PixelSize + 2] = 0;   //Red   0-255
            row[x*PixelSize + 3] = 50;  //Alpha 0-255
        }
    }
}

bmp.UnlockBits(bmd);

bmp.Save("test.png",ImageFormat.Png);
```

Alpha channel: 0 being fully transparent, 255 being no transparency on that pixel.

I'm sure you can easily modify the loop for painting a rectangle :)

Comment: Can't you do this in one loop? It'll be a lot faster already.

Comment: the second loop is run multiple times for each rectangle or transparency I apply to the bitmap. combining loops still won't produce a result as fast as using unsafe code..

Comment: You are correctly using the `Width` and `Height` properties of your `BitmapData` object inside your loops. Accessing these properties on the `Bitmap` itself would slow the code down (this is a common mistake in .NET image processing).

Answer (score 1):

You can still speed up your loop by quite a lot, by doing fewer write operations.

Create a single row of bytes in a buffer, and ask the .net runtime to copy those to managed memory. This is roughly 10-15 times faster on my computer.

```
// Build a "row" array and copy once for each row
// You can also build the full byte array and do only one
// call to Marshal.Copy, but that of course takes more memory.

var bytesPerPixel = 4;
byte[] row = new byte[bmp.Width * bytesPerPixel];
for (var i = 0; i < bmp.Width; ++i)
{
    var offset = i * bytesPerPixel;

    row[offset+0] = 0; //Blue  0-255
    row[offset+1] = 255; //Green 0-255
    row[offset+2] = 0;   //Red   0-255
    row[offset+3] = 50;  //Alpha 0-255
}

var bits = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);
for (var i = 0; i < bits.Height; ++i)
{
    Marshal.Copy(row, 0, bits.Scan0 + (i * bits.Stride), row.Length);
}
bmp.UnlockBits(bits);
```

If you want to keep your "one loop iteration for each pixel", you should at least only write each pixel value once. This halves the running time on my computer.

```
var pixel = (uint)(a << 24) | (uint)(r << 16) | (uint)(g << 8) | (b);
unsafe
{
    for (int y = 0; y < bmd.Height; y++)
    {
        var row = (uint*) ((byte*)bmd.Scan0 + (y * bmd.Stride));

        for (int x = 0; x < bmd.Width; x++)
        {
            row[x] = pixel;
        }
    }
}
```