# How can i change the method that compare two images to be faster?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the method im using today:

```
public static Bitmap CloudsOnly(Bitmap bitmapwithclouds, Bitmap bitmapwithoutclouds)
        {
            Color color;
            Color backgroundColor = Color.Black;

            CreateErrorsArray(bitmapwithclouds, bitmapwithoutclouds);

            int tolerance = tolerancenum * tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric + tolerancenumeric * tolerancenumeric;
            Bitmap newbitmap = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            for (int x = 0; x < bitmapwithclouds.Width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < bitmapwithclouds.Height; y++)
                {
                    int error = errorsArray[x, y];

                    if (error < tolerance)
                    {
                        color = backgroundColor;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        color = bitmapwithclouds.GetPixel(x, y);
                    }
                    newbitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color);
                }
            }
            newbitmap.Save(@"d:\test\newbitmap.jpg");
            return newbitmap;
        }
```

But GetPixel is slow i searched google and found some methods using LockBits for example this method:

```
private bool CompareBitmaps(Image left, Image right)
        {
            if (object.Equals(left, right))
                return true;
            if (left == null || right == null)
                return false;
            if (!left.Size.Equals(right.Size) || !left.PixelFormat.Equals(right.PixelFormat))
                return false;

            Bitmap leftBitmap = left as Bitmap;
            Bitmap rightBitmap = right as Bitmap;
            if (leftBitmap == null || rightBitmap == null)
                return true;

            #region Optimized code for performance

            int bytes = left.Width * left.Height * (Image.GetPixelFormatSize(left.PixelFormat) / 8);

            bool result = true;
            byte[] b1bytes = new byte[bytes];
            byte[] b2bytes = new byte[bytes];

            BitmapData bmd1 = leftBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, leftBitmap.Width - 1, leftBitmap.Height - 1), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, leftBitmap.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData bmd2 = rightBitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, rightBitmap.Width - 1, rightBitmap.Height - 1), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, rightBitmap.PixelFormat);

            Marshal.Copy(bmd1.Scan0, b1bytes, 0, bytes);
            Marshal.Copy(bmd2.Scan0, b2bytes, 0, bytes);

            for (int n = 0; n <= bytes - 1; n++)
            {
                if (b1bytes[n] != b2bytes[n])
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            leftBitmap.UnlockBits(bmd1);
            rightBitmap.UnlockBits(bmd2);

            #endregion

            return result;
        }
```

But this one just tell me if one image is the same like the second one.
I want to use my method above but with LockBits or some way faster.

How can i change my method the first one above to be faster ?

Comment: would you be able to do this quicker using the System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes class and System.Drawing.Imaging.ColorMap class to do this faster? Just a shot in the dark. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageAttributes_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would be cool if you explained what is your method supposed to do

Comment: The use of `LockBits` should be what you are looking for, if it does not work, it's because there is something wrong in your code, `LockBits` is what we use to process much heavily with image in .NET, it's much faster than GetPixel and SetPixel which can only be used when you just need to get/set the pixel once or several times.

Comment: I would avoid using `Marshal.Copy` and instead write some unsafe code directly accessing the bitmap data.

Comment: Lasse can you show me a code according to my code how to do it ?

Comment: athabaska this method get two images both weather radar one is empty reference radar image without clouds on it. The second is the same radar image with clouds in it. The method return image that show only clouds without the radar background colors only black image with the clouds on it. And since i need to scan the pixels over the bitmaps its slow.

Comment: athabaska i see the slow problem when i use a numericupdown to change the tolerance value in the method and since its scanning each time i change the numericupdown value all the images again its slow when i click on the numericupdown to change the value its taking like 2-3 seconds untill i see the value in the numericupdown change.

Comment: To fix the delay, postpone actually updating the image(s) until 0.5-3 seconds after the numeric up/down has been changed. You can accomplish that by having a timer with the right interval, and every time you change the numeric editor, first stop, and then start the timer. This will restart the delay. In the event, stop the timer, to avoid it updating the image(s) more than once. Also, you should look at running the image analysis on a background thread instead, then you can drop the timer as well.

Comment: The approach I suggested in my comment above may be your quickest option, It's used within the framework internally for fast color remapping. You would basically use the ImageAttributes to specify a remapping of any colors known to be part of the color palette for the blank radar (remapping them to black I suppose) leaving only the clouds. I don't play alot with image processing but I think there is a way to "get" the color palette for an image too. This would remove the need to manually get/set pixels.

Answer (score 2):

GetPixel is terrible slow, don't use it if you have more than one pixel and you don't want to spend your childhood by watching your code crawling through a picture.

You have to use unsafe code (unmanaged) for fast accessing of picture. See this post for help:
[C# Bitmap using unsafe code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7433508/c-sharp-bitmap-using-unsafe-code)

Performance comparison:  [C# Image Processing Performance - Unsafe vs. Safe code, Part II](http://davidthomasbernal.com/blog/2008/03/14/c-image-processing-performance-unsafe-vs-safe-code-part-ii/)

Comment: I would have to agree. Pointers are blazing fast for large iterative functions like this.

Answer (score -2):

I can recommend one naive optimization.
Instead of manualy comparing each byte in resulting array you can use hash funciton. It means that next code:

```
 for (int n = 0; n <= bytes - 1; n++)
            {
                if (b1bytes[n] != b2bytes[n])
                {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
```

can be replaced with

```
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
return sha1.ComputeHash(b1bytes) == sha1.ComputeHash(b2bytes);
```

Build in hash functions are well optimized.