# Parallel.Foreach and for each producing different results: Why is my code unsafe?

Tags: c#, concurrency, thread-safety, parallel.foreach

I have a text file which I read to a string `content`. To identify the textbody which I want to process further I am getting the indexes of keywords in the string and then set the "starting" index to the smallest index found.

I tried this with `Parallel.ForEach` ...

```
ConcurrentBag<int> indexes = new();
int index;

switch (Case)
{
    case 1:
        Parallel.ForEach(KeywordTypes.GetImplementedNamedObjects(), inos =>
        {
            index = content.IndexOf($"/begin {inos}");
            index = index == -1 ? content.Length : index;
            indexes.Add(index);
        });
        index = indexes.Min();
        return index;
```

... and with `foreach`:

```
foreach (string inos in KeywordTypes.GetImplementedNamedObjects())
{
    index = content.IndexOf($"/begin {inos}");
    index = index == -1 ? content.Length : index;
    indexes.Add(index);
}

index = indexes.Min();
return index;
```

where `foreach` produces the expected result but `Parallel.ForEach` does not.

Why is my code not thread-safe?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Marc already found the problem. I tried locking Indexes although it was a thread-safe variable but totally forgot about int index itself, which I am declaring out of the Parallel.Foreach which leads to unsafe accessing of the variable. I did this because I am using it in multiple switch statements and that´s why it is failing.

Comment: As a side note, in case it was important to get the `indexes` in the order of insertion, you could switch from the `ConcurrentBag<int>` to a `ConcurrentQueue<int>`. But in general when you want to do parallel work and you want the results back, the `PLINQ` library (the `AsParallel` LINQ operator) is more suitable than the `Parallel` class. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62656615/how-to-enforce-a-sequence-of-ordered-execution-in-parallel-for/62662369#62662369).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one `index` variable here, because it is "captured". This means that multiple threads can be squabbling over it, instead of having their own version each.

Consider:

- thread A computes `index = content.IndexOf($"/begin {inos}");`
- thread B computes `index = content.IndexOf($"/begin {inos}");` - oops, thread A's version just got overwritten
- thread A computes `index = index == -1 ? content.Length : index;` using the `index` that B just updated
- etc

the point is: a value got lost due to thread contention.

Simply move the declaration of `index` to fix this:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(KeywordTypes.GetImplementedNamedObjects(), inos =>
{
    var index = content.IndexOf($"/begin {inos}");
    ...
```

Fundamentally, the scope of a variable is defined by where it is declared. If a variable is declared *outside* of a local method / lambda, the compiler respects what you've asked, and that variable is shared between all uses of that local method / lambda; if it is declared *inside* the local method / lambda, then the lifetime is local to that invocation, and no state is shared between the callers.

If you want to be absolutely sure you're not accidentally leaking state, the `static` modifier on a lambda achieves this, although it also prevents `indexes` being accessed, so ... probably not what you need here.

Comment: Man I feel really stupid right now. Thank you very much!
Originally I coded it correctly but starting using `index` in multiple switch cases and moved the declaration outside of the Parallel.Foreach scope. But thanks for explaining it in depth again!

Comment: @MichaelS threading, parallelism, and state contention is just about the hardest thing in programming; there's no "stupid" here - just new things to learn